# fancybox - popup window size

Tags: fancybox

I am using FancyBox and I am having a slight problem.

I have a box, that is 930px wide where users can interact with things inside the popup.

The problem is, when a user in using a screen resolution that is, lets say 800x600, some of the items in the box do not display. The box has a fixed height and width (930x400).

I have tried to use `scrolling: auto` and `scrolling: yes` but nothing seems to work

Is there a way around this?

Thanks

UPDATE: - Included code snippet

```
$.fancybox({ 
           "padding" : 3, 
           "type":"iframe",  
           "href":"/requirements/"+$(".sf_admin_form_field_id div.content").html()+"/edit?req_id="+$(this).children(".id").children("div").children("input").val(), 
           "width" : 934, 
           "height" : 391, 
           "overlayShow": true,  
           "overlayOpacity" : 0, 
           "scrolling" : "yes", 
           "onClosed" : function(){ window.location.reload(); 
           }
```

Comment: Which version of fancybox is this?? Also is the content inside the popup in an iframe? Or does it just point to a dom element on the page??

Comment: FancyBox 1.3.4 and yes, it opens an iframe

Comment: This is why v2 has maxWidth/minWidth

Comment: Would it be worth upgrading to v2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`scrolling: 'auto'` (note the quotes!)

and if this does not work can you include the fancybox initializer that you are using??

Comment: Add the javascript in my question

Comment: So I assume `scrolling: "auto"` did nothing??

Comment: Sorry I think I just spotted the problem. The content in the box will not scroll because you have SET the width and height of the fancybox in pixels. What I think you need to do is detect the dimensions of the screen resolution and set the width and height as a percentage of that.

Comment: Use `$(window).width()` or `$(window).height()` to get the width/height of the browser. Then `"width" : $(window).width() * 0.90` will make fancybox 90% width of the browser, for example.